# I can't display both widget in Python

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn python and I'm having problem with displaying two widget at the same time. I was trying to create a Text area where I will put a string then submit this string.
This string will be use in `SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` to check the sentiment.

My goal now is to display the two widget using `ipywidgets` below is my code

```
   from ipywidgets import Textarea, Button

   textarea = Textarea(
      value='Sample value',
      disabled=False
    )

    button = Button(
               description='Submit Sentiment',
               disabled=False,
               button_style='', 
               tooltip='Submit',
               icon='paper-plane'
            )

    textarea
    button
```

When I run the code only the button is displaying, so I tried to comment out for the meantime the button variable and as expected the textarea variable shows.

I tried different approach like concatenation and using `IPython.display` as well but it display errors instead.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run this. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You should add the import statements and make it a reproducible example.

Comment: @Demi-Lune I add `from ipywidgets import Textarea, Button` but I'm still having errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `IPython.display` again, my wrong way is that I put the both variables inside the `display()`

Here's my code

```
   from ipywidgets import Textarea, Button
   from IPython.display import display

   tx = Textarea(value='test',disabled=False)
   btn = Button( description='Submit',disabled=False,button_style='', 
   tooltip='Submit',icon='paper-plane')

   display(tx)
   display(btn)
```

Finally both widget display.